# Twilio : Download Voice(phone) Recording MP3 with PHP Client (Or plain HTTP)

Tags: php, twilio

So I have been playing with Twilio the last few days and jsut can't figure out how to download the MP3 of a recording ?
I've managed to dial and record with PHP but when I can't seem to download the actual mp3 file with PHP Code ?

```
...
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

foreach ($twilio->recordings->read() as $call) {
   //This prints out ID      
   var_dump($call->sid);

   /*
     How do I download the mp3 of recording ?
   */

}
...
```

Comment: It looks like this isn't supported within the API: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/515#issuecomment-559274923  So you'll probably have to just use cURL to download the file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59843495/2577244

Answer (score 0):

It seems PatrickQ is right. There is no way todo via library. I had to issue a curl-cmd